# Trying to find $E_n=-E_1/n^2$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, atomic-physics

I'm reviewing some questions in an old math methods book after a long gap in math and physics for practice, and I think I'm missing something with this question since I always end up with an extra $\epsilon_o$.

Question:
[image: Added a screenshot of the question]
Starting with
$$
\frac{m v^2}{r}=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_e^2}{r^2} 
$$

$$
E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_e^2}{r}
$$

$$
L=mvr=\frac{nh}{2 \pi}
$$

Get:
$$
E_n=-\frac{E_1}{n^2}$$ 
where $E_1=\frac{mq_e^4}{8 \epsilon_o h^2}$

My work so far:
$$
mv^2=\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_e^2}{r}$$
so
$$E=\frac{1}{2}mv^2-\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q^2}{r}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_e^2}{r}-\frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_e^2}{r}=-\frac{1}{8 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_e^2}{r}$$
Then I played with it to try and get $n$ and $h$ out of it
$$
E=-\frac{1}{8 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{q_e^2}{r}\frac{m^2v^2r}{m^2 v^2 r}=-\frac{m^2 v^2 r q_e^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{1}{(mvr)^2}
$$

$$
E=-\frac{m^2 v^2 r q_e^2}{8 \pi \epsilon_o}\frac{4 \pi^2}{n^2h^2}
$$
Then I tried to play with it to get $E_1$.
$$
E=-\frac{mq_e^4}{8 \epsilon_o h^2}\frac{m v^2 r 4 \pi}{q_e^2 n^2}=-\frac{E_1}{n^2}\frac{m v^2 r 4 \pi}{q_e^2}
$$
So unless I messed up, I need to show $\frac{m v^2 r 4 \pi}{q_e^2}=1$. I started by trying to using the first equation. But its missing an epsilon so instead I get
$$
\frac{1}{\epsilon_o}=\frac{m v^2 r 4 \pi}{q_e^2}
$$
or
$$
E=-\frac{E_1}{n^2}\frac{m v^2 r 4 \pi}{q_e^2}=-\frac{E_1}{n^2}\frac{1}{\epsilon_o}
$$
Can anyone show me what I'm doing wrong or maybe a better way of solving it?

Comment: This question needs context. What is the energy you are trying to solve for? We dont know what your variables mean so we can't help

Comment: @doublefelix : OP is trying to derive the quantized energy levels of the hydrogen atom using Bohr's model.

Comment: Hi user246067,  $E_1 = {{mq_e^4} \over {8\epsilon_0^2h^2}}$. You missed a second factor of $\epsilon_0$ in the denominator while defining $E_1$. Redefine $E_1$ correctly and you shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Hello @AjayMohan, Are you sure? I edited the post with a screenshot of the question. If you are right, that would fix everything. If it is just a typo, that would be great.

Comment: Yes, one can even check its dimensions to be sure. The formula for Bohr radius given in question, $a_0$, is correct and we can use that to write ${E_1}_{\text{given in question}} = {{{q_e}^2}\over{8 \pi a_0}}$. But this is not dimensionally correct because we know that the work done in bringing two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ to a separation of $r$, which were initially infinitely separated, is ${{q_1q_2} \over{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r}}$. And this work done (which becomes the potential energy) has an extra factor of $\epsilon_0$ in the denominator, while it's missing in the $E_1$ given in the question.

Comment: @AjayMohan That makes sense. Thank you. That has been driving me crazy.